# How would one describe stacked diagonal patterns

Tags: patterns, design-principles

What is the best way to describe these type of visual patterns of diagonals stacked on top of each other? Is this a type of style or pattern with a proper name?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Those are two separate patterns..

The top one "cobblestone" perhaps... Although it's a bit loose. 
It's really just a simple diamond/square pattern.

The bottom one.. "scales" as in fish scales.

Comment: They are 2 distinct things but the patterns are similar. Cobblestone patterns vary. So do scales. I'm referring to the idea of diagonals stacked onto each other. I'm talking about the arrangement not the object

Comment: I'm sorry.. I feel a "scales" pattern is *exactly* what you are referring to. Your first image is nothing more than a pattern fo squares... nothing overlaps and it's not diagonal if the camera perspective was changed.

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Osborn_1912_trachodon_scale_pattern.png

are these scales? Do they look the same as the scales in the 2nd picture?

Comment: in the post, the rows don't sit next to each other. The stones and scales are adjacent to each other only in the diagonal not the row.

Comment: Yes that's a scale pattern.. no it's not the *same* scale pattern as the image in the question. But chicken is chicken, whether fried, baked or boiled. You're implying [this](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/11AfPGOKidL._SX331_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg) may be blue, but that means [this](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/external/slideshow/full/Sky%20Blue_full.png) can't also be blue. And the cobblestone is *not* a diamond or diagonal.. the **camera** is placed so it **looks* like diagonals. but walk ~15 paces to the left .. it's squares and not diagonal.

Comment: Asked about a pattern. A pattern is a repeated design. I didn't ask about the material or color or what the pattern is constructed with. Scales have different patterns. I wouldn't call green fractals a "green pattern". Yes, the cobblestones are squares. In this perspective look like squares in a stacked diagonal pattern. I'm aware that changing the perspective of this one changes things. Which is why I provided the scales. Does this have a name yes or no

Comment: As I've posted.. scale pattern and square/diamond pattern.